# 3 master-slave Datagrids are shown horinzontally

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am a WPF newbie. I have a WPF application. And on one of WPF forms, there needs to show a 3 WPF datagrid controls whose behaviors are in cascading way.

Datagrid1 is shown on the left; datagrid2 is shown in the middle; datagrid3 is shown on the right.  And those 3 datagrids, hence, are shown **horizontally**. Datagrid1 shows customers; datagrid2 shows orders of a specific customer; datagrid3 shows order details of a specific order.

When user clicks on a customer row of datagrid1, the application is able to load that customer's orders in datagrid2.  When user clicks on an order row of datagrid2, the application is able to show order details of that order in datagrid3.

Please give me some ideas how to do that functionality. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the MVVM pattern, and MVVM implementations of Master/Detail scenarios. Here is [some sample code on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-MVVM-Examples-fb8c409f) that demonstrates both of these to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" MinWidth="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:TestViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding CustomerId}" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid MinWidth="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderDetails}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsEnabled="{Binding OrderDetailsEnabled}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Details ID" Binding="{Binding OrderDetailsId}" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding OrderAddress}" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Time" Binding="{Binding OrderTime}" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid MinWidth="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" IsEnabled="{Binding OrderEnabled}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order ID" Binding="{Binding OrderId}" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prod Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

TestViewModel.cs

```
class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _orderEnable = false;

    public bool OrderEnabled
    {
        get { return _orderEnable; }
        set { _orderEnable = value; RaisePropertyChanged("OrderEnabled"); }
    }

    private bool _orderDetailsEnabled = false;

    public bool OrderDetailsEnabled
    {
        get { return _orderDetailsEnabled; }
        set { _orderDetailsEnabled = value; RaisePropertyChanged("OrderDetailsEnabled"); }
    }



    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
    }

    private IEnumerable<OrderDetail> _orderDetails;

    public IEnumerable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails
    {
        get { return _orderDetails; }
        set { _orderDetails = value; RaisePropertyChanged("OrderDetails"); }
    }


    private IEnumerable<Order> _orders;

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return _orders; }
        private set
        {
            _orders = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Orders");
            OrderDetailsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private Order _selectedOrder;

    public Order SelectedOrder
    {
        get { return _selectedOrder; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && _selectedOrder != value)
            {
                _selectedOrder = value;
                OrderDetails = _selectedOrder.OrderDetails;
                OrderDetailsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private Customer _selectedCustomer;

    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && _selectedCustomer != value)
            {
                _selectedCustomer = value;
                Orders = _selectedCustomer.Orders;
                OrderEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        _customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_customers, _lock);
        _customers.Add(new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 1,
            FirstName = "TestFirst",
            LastName = "TestLast",
            Orders = new List<Order> { new Order { OrderId = 1, ProductName = "ProdOneOne", 
                OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail> { new OrderDetail { OrderDetailsId = 1, OrderAddress = "EarthOneOne", OrderTime = DateTime.Now  } } },
            new Order { OrderId = 2, ProductName = "ProdOneTwo", 
                OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail> { new OrderDetail { OrderDetailsId = 2, OrderAddress = "EarthOneTwo", OrderTime = DateTime.Now } } }}
        });

        _customers.Add(new Customer
        {
            CustomerId = 2,
            FirstName = "FirstTest",
            LastName = "LastTest",
            Orders = new List<Order> { new Order { OrderId = 1, ProductName = "ProdTwoOne", 
                OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail> { new OrderDetail { OrderDetailsId = 1, OrderAddress = "EarthTwoOne", OrderTime = DateTime.Now } } },
            new Order { OrderId = 2, ProductName = "ProdTwTwo", 
                OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail> { new OrderDetail { OrderDetailsId = 2, OrderAddress = "EarthTwoTwo", OrderTime = DateTime.Now } } } }
        });
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}



public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailsId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
    public string OrderAddress { get; set; }
}
```

It is quite lengthy to see but very easy to understand. I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind efforts. I will try that.